# Annotation in stacked bar chart -achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

1. I m willing to draw a aChartEngine Stacked bar chart and everthing
   works fine but the annotation below in bar[green color] is ligter
   and is not represented properly..i need custom label in middlt of
   the bar so used annotations
2. when i make lable color as white it is not shown also since
   background is white , how to make textlable formating of annotations
   in achartengine?
3. Anyidea how to add textview at x y position in achrtengine?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For annotations properties .

```
 XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();

 r.setAnnotationsColor(Color.RED);
 r.setAnnotationsTextSize(20);
```